# I cannot cut using knife tool to make a polygon with 4 vertices

Tags: modeling, topology, knife-tool

I have started using blender today, I saw a video on Youtube and was trying the create a similar model but I am unable to cut the vertices to make it a polygon using knife tool.

Whenever I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it just doesn't cut and make it a polygon. Please help me to make this face polygon instead of NGON.

I want to make the bottom face which you can see a collection of polygons not ngons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use punctuation in your questions

Comment: Please try remove doubles and if that doesn't remove the problem, please upload your .blend file or more screen shots.

Comment: i tried doing that, but i cant see anything happening. Also i have included one more mesh(in the blend file i have uploaded) i want to delete that complete mesh other than my main chest model, please let me know how can i do that also.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4371" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4371/)

Comment: Are you quite sure remove doubles does nothing?(I cannot check the.blend file right now. sorry) I guess you're in the face select mode and you seem to have some faces squashed into edges (edges with a black dot in the middle). Try it with a bigger merge distance.

Comment: yes thanks,some faces squashed into edges (edges with a black dot in the middle) and it worked with a bigger merge distance. it helped.